# How to get search operation parameter in server side in jqGrid?

Tags: jquery, jsp, jqgrid, jqgrid-php

I have typed in id filter box 5 and I have choosen greater in search operations. I got a id=5 value at server end but I can't get the `value()` for search operator.

```
    jQuery("#list451").jqGrid({
    url: 'localset.do',
    datatype: "json",
    height: 255,
    width: 600,
    colNames: ['id', 'name', 'Code'],
    colModel: [{
        name: 'item_id',
        index: 'item_id',
        width: 65,
        sorttype: 'integer',
        searchoptions: {
            sopt: ['eq', 'ne', 'le', 'lt', 'gt', 'ge']
        }
    }, {
        name: 'name',
        index: 'name',
        width: 150,
        sorttype: 'string',
        searchoptions: {
            sopt: ['eq', 'bw', 'bn', 'cn', 'nc', 'ew', 'en']
        }
    }, {
        name: 'item_cd',
        index: 'item_cd',
        width: 100
    }],
    rowNum: 50,
    rowTotal: 200,
    rowList: [20, 30, 50],
    loadonce: false,
    mtype: "GET",
    rownumbers: true,
    rownumWidth: 40,
    gridview: true,
    pager: '#pager451',
    sortname: 'item_id',
    viewrecords: true,
    sortorder: "asc",
    caption: "Loading data from server at once"
});
jQuery("#list451").jqGrid('filterToolbar', {
    searchOperators: true
});
```

i have tried  `postdata:{ filters: JSON.stringify(searchOper) }`

I am using jsp servlet.

The request query string is:

```
&page=&_search=false&nd=1408689334839&rows=10&page=1&sidx=&sord=asc&id=5
```

How to get the id search operator value?

Please Help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `stringResult: true` option of [filterToolbar](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:toolbar_searching#calling_convention). Currently you use legacy form which just send the name and the value of searched option. More recent format used everywhere in jqGrid are described [here](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:advanced_searching#options). As the result all information about the filter and operations will be send as one `filters` parameter.

I use always `stringResult: true` option in `filterToolbar` and `multipleSearch: true` (or both `multipleSearch: true` and `multipleGroup: true`) in all my productive codes. To simplify the usage of such options everywhere I set my favorite searching/filter options by including the line like

```
$.extend(true, $.jgrid.search, {
    jqModal: false,
    multipleSearch: true,
    multipleGroup: true,
    recreateFilter: true,
    closeOnEscape: true,
    searchOnEnter: true,
    overlay: 0,
    stringResult: true,
    defaultSearch: "cn"
});
```

directly after including `grid.locale-en.js` and `jquery.jqGrid.min.js`.

You will have to adjust your server code of course to parse `filters` parameter.

Comment: Oleg please answer the below question.... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25500284/how-to-disable-search-opertion-for-seleted-column-in-jqgrid