# How to disable search opertion for seleted column in jqGrid?

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, jqgrid-php

I have a five column(2 integer,3 String column) grid with column filter. i want search operations for integer values(greater,less,equal) its working fine, i don't want search operations for string column.

I am using back end search.

What am expecting is attached the model image as below please find it

**i want search but i don't want search operations for String having columns**

**How to remove search operations in selected column. please help me.**

[image]

```
jQuery("#list451").jqGrid({
    url: 'localset.php',
    datatype: "json",
    height: 255,
    width: 600,
    colNames: ['Index', 'Name', 'Code', 'N Name', 'C Name'],
    colModel: [{
            name: 'item_id',
            index: 'item_id',
            width: 65,
            sorttype: 'integer',
            searchoptions: {
                sopt: ['eq', 'ne', 'le', 'lt', 'gt', 'ge']
            }
        }, {
            name: 'name',
            index: 'name',
            width: 150,
            sorttype: 'string',
            searchoptions: {
                sopt: []
            }
        }, {
            name: 'code',
            index: 'code',
            width: 150,
            sorttype: 'string',
            searchoptions: {
                sopt: ['eq', 'bw', 'bn', 'cn', 'nc', 'ew', 'en']
            }
        }, {
            name: 'n_name',
            index: 'n_name',
            width: 150,
            sorttype: 'string',
            searchoptions: {
                sopt: []
            }
        }, {
            name: 'c_name',
            index: 'c_name',
            width: 150,
            sorttype: 'string',
            searchoptions: {
                sopt: []
            }
        },
        rowNum: 50,
        rowTotal: 200,
        rowList: [20, 30, 50],
        loadonce: true,
        mtype: "GET",
        rownumbers: true,
        rownumWidth: 40,
        gridview: true,
        pager: '#pager451',
        sortname: 'item_id',
        viewrecords: true,
        sortorder: "asc",
        caption: "Loading data from server at once"
    }); jQuery("#list451").jqGrid('filterToolbar', {
    searchOperators: true
});
```

Comment: please share html and jquery code that you have tried so far.

Comment: Are you using the javascript plugin? Or jqgrid-php, asp?

Comment: sample code added please check update....am using jqgrid.js with php

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jqGrid: Search Toolbar disable for some columns?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6114613/jqgrid-search-toolbar-disable-for-some-columns)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find your question very interesting and so I prepared [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/SelectiveSearchOperations.htm) which shows how the problem can be solved. The results looks like on the picture below:

[image]

The current version of jqGrid support `clearSearch` which can be defined for every specific column, but it didn't support column specific `searchOperators` option. There are only `searchOperators` option of `filterToolbar` applied to all columns.

The demo calls `normalizeFilterToolbar` function which hide the part of searching input with the searing operation for all columns where either new `searchOperators: false` option are used in the column definition or where *only one* operation are specified (for example is no `sopt` are defined in `searchoptions` or if no `searchoptions` at all are defined). The corresponding code looks

```
var $grid = $("#list"), // the grid
    normalizeFilterToolbar = function () {
        var $self = this,
            colModel = $self.jqGrid("getGridParam", "colModel"),
            $searchToolbarColumns = $self.closest(".ui-jqgrid-view")
                .find(">.ui-jqgrid-hdiv .ui-jqgrid-htable .ui-search-toolbar>.ui-th-column"),
            cCol = colModel.length,
            iCol,
            cm;

        for (iCol = 0; iCol < cCol; iCol++) {
            cm = colModel[iCol];
            if (cm.searchoptions == null ||
                    ((cm.searchoptions.sopt == null || cm.searchoptions.sopt.length === 1) && cm.searchoptions.searchOperators !== true) ||
                    (cm.searchoptions.searchOperators === false)) {
                // hide the searching operation for the column
                $($searchToolbarColumns[iCol]).find(">div>.ui-search-table .ui-search-oper").hide();
            }
        }
    };

// create the grid
$grid.jqGrid({
    // ... the options
});

$grid.jqGrid("filterToolbar", {searchOperators: true, defaultSearch: "cn"});
normalizeFilterToolbar.call($grid);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Oleg. Oleg its working very fine.Very Nice Example.

Comment: How to add Reset search value x button in number format text box. Oleg Please add the code .

Comment: @KrishnakumarSubbaiyan: One can define `clearSearch: false` or `clearSearch: true` (default is true) in every column. I used `clearSearch: false` in `numberTemplate` in my demo. Just remove `clearSearch: false` if you need to see "x" button in numeric searching fields.

Answer (score 2):

Use `search:false` in your **colModel** for columns you dont need searching.

**UPDATE**
You can customize the search option in your Grid by replacing **searchoptions:** with **searchrules**

```
searchrules:{custom:true, custom_func: fnc_myStringCheck }, search:true }
```

Make sure the **stype** is text (though it is by default) and **fnc_myStringCheck** for your custom method. 
Hope this helps.

Comment: i want search but i don't want search operations

Comment: Can you explain why you need a filter column without any search option.

Comment: integer columns i want search operations. String column i will implement customized search like (Lor*  /man). so i want search without search operations.

Comment: Wahab Thanks for spend time for me. .i don't want put every column search rules.please help me for remove search operations for string columns.

Comment: I am sorry, i couldn't understand ur requirement. "i don't want put every column search rules" then use a generalized search like this **grid.jqGrid('filterToolbar', {autosearch : true, searchOnEnter:false, defaultSearch : "cn",});** but if you want to have customized search for column u hav to implement individually in colModel

Comment: Hi Wahab, i will implement many different type of customize search for every column. so it will implement back end side. i want remove search operations only,Please you don't worry about my requirement.

Answer (score 0):

**static way**:

```
colModel : [ 
                    {
                        name : 'sequenceId',
                        index : ' ',
                        search: false,
                        sortable : true,
                        classes: 'wrap'
                    }
```

**dynamic way**:

```
colModel : [ 
                    {
                        name : 'sequenceId',
                        index : ' ',
                        sortable : true,
                        classes: 'wrap',
                        formatter: disableSearch
                    }
function disableSearch(cellvalue, options, rowObject) {
    options.colModel.search = false;
    return cellvalue;
}
```